# How to run geth --fast on OSX

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I am having problems getting Mist to sync, so would like to run geth --fast.  I can not find the folder to run geth from?  Do I need to install it separately, I thought it was bundled with Mist?  I am new to terminal so some basic instructions would be appreciated. Any help would be appreciated.  I am running OS X 10.11.4 and Ethereum-Wallet-macosx-0-7-2.

Comment: I've followed every set of instructions I can find and it still takes forever. geth --fast doesn't speed it up at all.

Comment: What times did you get with and without the `--fast` flag? Were they both a similar order of magnitude?

Comment: tried following these instructions but doesn't seem to work anymore. Has something been updated or am I missing something? (I am not a programmer just trying to get a working ehter wallet as it is no pretty much mathematically impossible to catch up with the blockchain)

Answer (score 6):

### Install geth - Mac

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac

1. Open Terminal.
2. Install homebrew by pasting this line and hitting enter : `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Install geth by running each of these in terminal one at a time (copy, paste, hit enter, wait)

`brew tap ethereum/ethereum`

`brew install ethereum`

### Run geth fast

1. Open Terminal and type `geth --fast` and hit enter

### Delete chaindata

If you have already started syncing Mist you may want to delete your chaindata. I would recommend doing this as it ensures you get the full benefits of --fast, and allows you to start fresh. For those re-syncing after months, it'll help eliminate corrupted chain files, ensure no problems from before homestead - > after homestead, and help get rid of bloat.

1. Open Mist and go Accounts - > backup - > accounts.
2. If you have any accounts, *copy* the files inside keystore (they look like `UTC-2016-5-16.......`) to your Desktop AND a USB drive (or two). These are your encrypted private keys. If you lose these, any ETH inside these accounts will be inaccessible and lost forever.
3. Go up a folder level and find the chaindata folder. Delete **just this chaindata folder.** Alternatively, you could move it to your Desktop if you think the sync might not work and you want to recover it later.
4. Then run `geth --fast`

**UPDATE:** `geth --fast` has been deprecated. Use `geth syncmode="light"` insted.

Comment: Great thanks for your detailed answer much appreciated :)  The chain finally synced by itself through Mist earlier today, so I am now up and running.  I tried installing Geth as you suggested and got a software version not compatible error.   But all good anyway now I am up to date.  Thanks again.